# Sinatra -read sqlite, output json

Tags: json, activerecord, sinatra, datamapper

Being a total ruby noob who found sinatra over the weekend i'm trying to setup a local json feed for developing a mobile app.

Every example shows how to access the sqlite file,define a model and then define the json output but they all assume you will define a new blank sqlite file and write to it-NOT loading existing data.or am i misinterpreting this?

I'm open to either libraries- active_record or datamapper(AR looks slightly easier as you don't have to define the table fields and datamapper's docs don't inspire me much).

Your input on any of this will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't know about ActiveRecord, but with DataMapper there's no mystery: you can easily use existing tables. You don't have to start with a blank database. Is there any point in particular that's causing you problems?

Comment: had left out auto_migrate - the main problem now is the to_json definition `get "/json" do content_type :json (train.all).to_json end`returns an empty array